# Stationary Probability Distribution of Switched Stochastic Process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, probability-limit-theorems

Let $v_k$ and $w_k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, be independent Gaussian processes with $v_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_v) $ and $w_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_w,\sigma_w)$. Let $p \in (0,1)$ and consider the switched process:
$$x_{k+1} = 
\cases{
ax_k + v_k  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad 1-p,\cr 
bx_k + w_k  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad p,
}$$
where $a,b \in (0,1)$ and "w.p." stands for "with probability". That is, with probability $p$, $x_{k+1}$ samples from $ax_k + v_k$, and with probability $1-p$, it samples from $bx_k + w_k$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I would like to find a closed form of the stationary distribution of $x_k$. From Monte Carlo simulations, I know it does have a stationary distribution. Moreover, for $b=0$, I can find a closed form of the distribution by writing $x_{k}$ as an infinite-dimensional Markov Chain. For $b=0$, the stationary distribution is an infinite Gaussian mixture given by
$$x_{k} \sim 
\cases{
\mathcal{N}(\mu_w,\sigma_w)  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad p,\cr 
\mathcal{N}(a\mu_w,a^2\sigma_w + \sigma_v)  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad (1-p)p,\cr 
\mathcal{N}(a^2\mu_w,a^4\sigma_w + (a^2+1)\sigma_v)  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad (1-p)^2p,\cr 
\mathcal{N}(a^3\mu_w,a^6\sigma_w + (a^4+a^2+1)\sigma_v)  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad (1-p)^3p,\cr 
\mathcal{N}(a^4\mu_w,a^8\sigma_w + (a^6 + a^4+a^2+1)\sigma_v)  \quad \text{ w.p. } \quad (1-p)^4p,\cr 
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots
}$$
Now, for $b \neq 0$, I cannot write the infinite-dimensional Markov Chain as every state has an infinite number of transitions. Any hint about how to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can check your answer (even for the $b=0$ case) by computing more basic things such as $m_k = E[X_k]$, where we have $$m_{k+1} = p(a m_k + 0) + (1-p)(bm_k+\mu) = m_k(pa+(1-p)b) + (1-p)\mu$$ This is a simple linear difference equation and so I get an answer of $$m_k=\frac{(1-p)\mu}{1-(pa+(1-p)b)} + \theta(pa+(1-p)b)^k \quad \forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$ for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\theta$ can be used to set the initial condition, and asuming $pa+(1-p)b\neq 1$.  You can also get an exact expression for the second moments $E[X_k^2]$ for all $k$.

Comment: Thanks. I can indeed compute some moments. I need however the stationary distribution. How having a few moments could help?

Comment: It gives a simple closed form result for mean and variance for all $k$ and for all choices of the parameters $a,b$. It also helps to check your work. For example, if $b=0$ and $|pa|<1$ we get $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} m_k = \frac{(1-p)\mu}{1-pa}$. Does that correspond to your answer? It seems your answer would give $$\mu\left[p + p(1-p)a + p(1-p)^2a^2 + p(1-p)^3a^4 + ???\right]$$ I cannot verify myself because I do not know what you intend for the sequence $\{1, a, a^2, a^4, ...???\}$ or how you get that answer. Is the next term supposed to be $a^6$? or $a^8$?

Comment: There were some typos in the problem formulation and solution. I have amended them now. The stationary distribution I show, for $b=0$, matches your computation. I can do the same for the variance. However, this is not what I need, I need the stationary distribution for $b \neq 0$.

Comment: What is the context here, why do you need the stationary distribution?

Comment: I need it to approximate the stationary cdf to compute probabilities. I need a good estimate of these probabilities so Markov like upper bounds in terms the first two moments won't help.